# Chat for SE meta sites

Tags: support, stack-exchange, chat, meta, per-site-meta

Will the SE meta sites ever get a chat option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/145938)

> (on sept 1 2010):
>   the first one might happen next week

Comment: Right on time, we have another chat server (not meta, though - chat is for both parent and meta). You've got to find which one, though ;p

Comment: @Marc, I follow balpha on twitter so I already know ;)

Answer (score 2):

No. Meta.SO is an exception (like in so many other cases).

For all other instances of chat, the main site will be considered the parent. So there will be chat.nothingtoinstall.com, but no chat.meta.nothingtoinstall.com.

I don't think there needs to be one chat for discussing the site's *topic* (web applications) and one chat for discussing the *site* (nothingtoinstall.com). This can very well happen on one single chat site.

That said, [Juan is correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63419/chat-for-se-meta-sites/63421#63421) in that we hope to roll out the first "normal" chat site next week.